# Making a portable (exe) with Python 3.1?

Tags: python, py2exe

Is there a way to make a portable/stand-alone exe for python apps?

I've read about p2exe but it doesn't support the latest version. I'm reluctant to go to 2.6 because I'd rather stay with the latest version instead of worrying about incompatibilities as soon as 2.6 becomes too outdated.

Comment: Isn't library incompatibilities the main reason that people aren't switching to Python 3?

Comment: @blahblah: Indeed it is. There are almost no 3rd party libs for Python 3 yet. But setuptools just became available through the distribute project, sp that might change soon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What technologies exist to create stand alone executables for Python 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447093/what-technologies-exist-to-create-stand-alone-executables-for-python-3)

Answer (score 13):

cx_freeze has worked for me.  Here's a link.  The page claims to support 3.1.  Good luck!

http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

Comment: To be honest I've never tried on 3.1, but it does work well for older stuff, so I presume they're not just lying to us! =)

Comment: Also check http://www.mail-archive.com/cx-freeze-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00212.html to get around some errors you might receive when building.