# What technologies exist to create stand alone executables for Python 3?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, executable

Other than [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/), are there any other current maintained tool suites to generate stand alone executables for Python 3k?

Are there any other techniques for minimizing preinstallation requirements under Windows?

Comment: Go is now becoming popular, and avoids this problem. Consider using Go for generating deployable binaries to different architectures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be another choice of tool at the moment.

There's nothing stopping you from including a prebuilt Python environment in your package/installer and either creating an appropriate shortcut to launch the Python app, or creating a separate executable that launches the Python app (or even linking the Python interpreter into the executable and using it like that...). It just takes some more effort making sure you've got all the right pieces (like .dlls) where they need to be.

Remember, Python doesn't have to be "installed" per se, you just need to make sure it knows where to find everything (e.g. set the appropriate environment variables like PYTHONPATH in whatever launcher you're using).

Comment: Could this be done most easily using `virtualenv`? Do you know of any tutorials that show how this could be done?

Answer (score 2):

I know of only `cx_Freeze` to build Python 3 executables. I asked a similar question a few month ago (which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737375/building-executables-for-python-3-and-pyqt)).
Maybe that already helps?

Comment: Hmm, a damn shame that nothing else exists. It's also a shame that Python makes for awful executables too.

Answer (score 1):

No, not yet.

There is just [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) which supports Python 2.3 or higher (including Python 3), since it makes use of the zip import facility which was introduced in 2.3.

For more information you can visit cx_freeze website here http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, I think [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) is a good option. It's described as follows:

> py2exe is a Python Distutils extension which converts Python scripts into executable Windows programs, able to run without requiring a Python installation.

And it works with Python 3.x.

(As a bonus, there's [py2app](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/) that does the trick on Mac OS X.)

Comment: py2exe is only available for 2.3 through 2.7. Where do you see a Python 3.x version?

Comment: You have to run py2exe with Python 2.3-2.7, but it can package Python 3 programs. There's a mention of one special consideration that applies to 2.6, 2.7, 3.0 and 3.1 in the tutorial (http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step529).

Comment: There's mention, but it sux. Big difference.

Comment: The question was "are there any other techniques". But fair enough.