# How to create windows 32/64 executable for a python script written in python 3.3.2?

Tags: python-3.x, executable

Please help me with the process needed to convert a python script to a windows executable.
On some web links I did find tutorials that mentioned using py2exe. However, i did not fins a version of py2exe that is compatible with python 3.3.2.

Is there any other way of creating a windows executable from python script written in version 3.3.2 ?

Please note that I need to run the executable on windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 2):

I found following useful links and cx_Freeze worked like a charm with a python script written in python 3.3.2.
Thanks to all for providing the useful information.

Useful links:

1. Useful [replies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447093/what-technologies-exist-to-create-stand-alone-executables-for-python-3?rq=1) for converting python script in 3.3.2 to windows executable.
2. [Download cx_Freeze and see relevant documentation.](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)
3. Once cx_Freeze is installed, use this [link](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/script.html#script) for other instructions.