# How can I use the py2exe to change the python3.2's code to exe

Tags: python, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [py2exe for Python 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505230/py2exe-for-python-3-0)

I read py2exe can create a standalone program using a Python version before the 3. How, using Python 3.2, create e.g. "Hello world.exe", please??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505783/making-a-portable-exe-with-python-3-1  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505230/py2exe-for-python-3-0

Comment: Go ahead and comment on the Python3 support feature request: https://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/feature-requests/20/

Answer (score 9):

p2exe is pretty much dead, unless you are using 2.7 or less.

1)  Look into [cx-freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)

2)  Install cx-freeze

3)  Create your script (test.py):

```
print("Hello there, anyone else hate hello worlds?")
```

---

4)  Create your setup.py file

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

 setup(
    name = "hatefulworld",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "I wish programming was this easy",
    executables = [Executable("test.py")])
```

---

5)  Execute the python command:

```
python setup.py build
```

---

6) **Cross your fingers, and if it was successful change to build\exe directory, and run your program.

---

I am glad you asked for a hello world tutorial, and not a useful one because its never as easy as above.

Comment: Except in Python 3.2 it should be print("Hello there...")

Comment: @phkanhler you are correct, some of us aren't allowed to run > 2.7 yet :(