# Python 3.2.2, error(scripts to exe)

Tags: python, executable

Hello i follow this instructions ([How can I use the py2exe to change the python3.2's code to exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425869/how-can-i-use-the-py2exe-to-change-the-python3-2s-code-to-exe)) to create exe form python scripts(version 3.2.2), but it report me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\Scripts\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    executables = [Executable("ochranka.py")])
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 365, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 136, in setup
    raise SystemExit(gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg)
SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help
error: no commands supplied
```

This is my setup.py file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(
    name = "Ochranka",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "test",
    executables = [Executable("ochranka.py")])
```

I am a beginner, I do not know what to do with it.

Answer (score 5):

You have to pass a command to `setup.py`; in this case, `build`*:

```
python setup.py build
```

I bet you forgot the `build` part.

*Note: I'm not 100% sure `build` is the command you want (it's been a while since I used cx_freeze). See [the documentation](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils).

Comment: build should do it, if you want to be able to omit it, use `import sys;sys.argv.append('build')`