# Cx-freeze cannot load pyglet.media module

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

In my python(3.4) file, I used pyglet.media module. Now I build an exe using `cx_Freeze` following structure of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820461/python-3-2-2-errorscripts-to-exe).My `setup.py` is :

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(
    name = "program",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "test",
    executables = [Executable("program.py")])
```

When I run the exe, I receive this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'pyglet.media'
```

I add `import pyglet`at the beginning of `setup.py` but still doesnt work.
How can I force importing pyglet.media module beside exe file?

I know there is a similar question in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205219/cx-freeze-fails-to-include-modules-even-when-included-specifically) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363919/cx-freeze-executable-importerror-no-module-named-zipfile?rq=1), but they are either old or there is no working answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should include pyglet package as options.

```
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["pyglet"]}

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "program",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "test",
    options = {"build_exe":build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("program.py")])
```