# a good python to exe compiler?

Tags: python

I am new to python and apart from the language itself, I am exploring various aspects of it. in terms of compilation into .exe (so that it can be deployed without installing python too)
I checked py2exe, new releases stopped a few years ago.
Then pyInstaller, seems to have stopped at python 2.7.

Can I get a list of all python to exe compilers? thanks

Comment: I had an impression that python cannot be compiled effectively due to its dynamic features. yes, there are tools that can produce an exe, but I thought that they rely on a runtime anyways.

Comment: For reference: `pyInstaller` is still under active development, and working on 3.x support, although I have no idea how far away it is. And `py2exe` already supports 3.x (although you have to run it under 2.7). This is just a comment, not an answer—cx_freeze is probably what you want.

Comment: @akonsu More or less true, the conclusion is either not true or not relevant. These tools include the runtime (as in, python.dll and all used modules) with the resulting executable, so it does not have dependencies (apart from the right version of the C runtime, I think, but a C executable needs that too).

Comment: @akonsu This term is at least ambiguous due to the widespread use in python (just search 'python compiler' on SO) to define several things (p.e there are pyc files as well as compiler module in the library -in py3k a built in compile function). IMHO the OP does not deserve those downvotes (similar posts with similar titles have been highly upvoted on SO).

Comment: possible duplicate of [making a python program executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286441/making-a-python-program-executable)

Answer (score 66):

- [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) for Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X (Python 3.5-3.10)
- [cx_Freeze](https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze) for Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X (Python 3.6-3.10)
- [bbfreeze](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze/) for Windows and Linux (Python 2.4-2.7)
- [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) for Windows (Python 2.6, 2.7)
- [py2exe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/) for Windows (Python 3.3-3.10)
- [Freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze) for Linux and maybe Mac OS X (Python 2.x)
- [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html) for Mac OS X (Python 2.x)
- [Nuitka](https://nuitka.net/) for Windows, Linux, and MacOS (2.6, 2.7, 3.3-3.9)

Comment: `bbfreeze` also doesn't work for 3.x, I believe `freeze` doesn't either, and `py2exe` just barely does. Implying that `pyinstaller` is the only one on your list that doesn't work for 3.x is misleading—especially since the OP pretty strongly implied that he wants 3.x support. (And the only one of your answers that works fine for 3.x is `py2app`, which isn't going to help the OP on Windows.)

Comment: pyinstaller now supports 3.3-3.5  :)

Comment: Successfully complied a Python 3.6 script using the "develop" branch of Pyinstaller (Github).

Comment: [http://pytoexe.com/](http://pytoexe.com/)  - online (havent tested)

Comment: http://deneskellner.local/sw/rapidexe - I mean, sorry for mentioning a product I've created, but it seems to solve the problem at hand. There's a Python example in the package.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze

Works fine for Python 3.x.

Otherwise you can always make your script run at Python 2.x and use a program that can transform from that version.

Also look up:

[Python 3.0.1 Executable Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702395/python-3-0-1-executable-creator)

[Making a portable (exe) with Python 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505783/making-a-portable-exe-with-python-3-1)

Comment: Also [What technologies exist to create stand alone executables for Python 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447093/what-technologies-exist-to-create-stand-alone-executables-for-python-3).

Answer (score 3):

I've had luck using [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) and the pyc.py tool. You can basically turn your python into .net bytecode and then to an exe.

Comment: yea, that is pretty much the way to go.

Comment: The second link is dead. The new link is probably as follows: http://dbaportal.eu/2009/12/21/ironpython-how-to-compile-exe/