# Is it possible to deploy python3 applications as self-executables in Mac, linux and Windows ? how?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

considering another stackoverflow question that was posted at 2009 and tools like py2exe that haven't been updated since 2008, is it possible ?

I am creating an application that saves and retrieves data from an sqlite db and I want to distribute it to my colleagues without having them to install python libraries and execute .py files. The application uses tkinter as a GUI library.

Is that possible in 2013 ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165398/a-good-python-to-exe-compiler

Comment: I have read those ones, I am interested in cross-platform deployment. It's not about commercial applications but for ones that I will use personally, like a task manager. Also, as I said py2exe has to be updated since 2008.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**, it is possible.

You may want to use the tool called **[cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)**, it creates an executable from a python3 application (including all the libraries it uses), and it does this **cross-platform**.

The only thing you need to know is that in order to create, let's say a windows executable, you must run cx_Freeze in windows. (same goes for MAC, linux, etc..)

You can read [here](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/script.html) about the usage of the script.

Good Luck!

Comment: where do I find it and what about depending files that need to be imported ?

Comment: the word `cx_Freeze` in my answer is a link, just click it ;). you don't need to import any other files, cx_Freeze knows what it needs and how to get it. if you see it doesn't include some module you need you can run it with the `–include-modules` argument and specify there what modules you want. as my answer says it's all written in the documentation which I also linked above. (click the word `here`).

Comment: thank God I know what a link is :) the download page of cxfreeze has windows msi's and rpms. I dismissed the "download source" link. The "documentation" you are referring to is a page with wildcards !

Comment: @RobertoDelgazzo Sorry but i don't understand your problem, can you explain it again?