# Python project to exe

Tags: python-2.7, executable, py2exe

I've been working on a rather large Python project containing both downloaded packages (xlwt, xlrd etc. ) and user defined packages and I'd like to pack it into a single .exe file. I've been searching, but can't seem to find something on how to make an executable from such a project. 
Any thoughts or links that might help?

EDIT: I've looked into Py2exe, cx_freeze etc. problem is that I can't find a description on how to make an exe file for a project with multiple user defined packages.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165398/a-good-python-to-exe-compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few projects that might interest you:

- [CX Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net)
- [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)
- [pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki)
- [bbfreeze](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze/1.1.3)

These essentially "freeze" your code ship it with a bundled Python interpreter.

Comment: Solved it using pyinstaller. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

There is py2exe extension that creates *.exe file for your Python application. See http://www.py2exe.org/ (and more specifically, http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial).

Comment: I've looked at this, but can't quite figure out how to do it when I have my modules in different packages. I've only managed to find a tutorials for single script exe conversion.

Comment: There are multiple options for py2exe such as includes, excludes and packages - you can find these at http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions. Specifying the correct packages should be enough to create an executable bundle.