# How to create exe using visual studio for a python code?

Tags: python, visual-studio

with visual studio 2013 i have opened my python code. And able to run as well. My query is how do i create exe for this python code using visual studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a good python to exe compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165398/a-good-python-to-exe-compiler)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a single executable from a Python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project)

Comment: What is your actual intention here? Do you want to give your code to someone else to use/execute it?

Answer (score 0):

Python is an interpreted language, not a compiled language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29

There are several way to pack (or event precompile) your code to exe, but you will need additional tools to implement it.