# Pyinstaller - Standalone .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an .exe file such that when run on any windows 10 pc will run without requiring any installations. What I tried using was:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

I ran the exe file on a friend's computer and it turns out that it required first python2.7 to be installed, then it said that modules weren't installed i.e; no module named datetime found. The executable finally ran after I installed all dependencies on my friend's computer but the whole point of creating .exe file was useless, I might as well have just typed `python main.py` after doing so much. Is there an appropriate way I could get an .exe file from .py which wont require anything to be installed? Like an actual standalone app. Thank you!

Comment: The whole point of pyinstaller is to avoid installing dependencies. I can't say what you're doing wrong for sure without more information so let me start with this:
What happens when your friend opens the main.exe file on his computer?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this should work. I never had problems with pyinstaller, yet. Maybe reinstall pyinstaller or make sure to use the newest version. Also try first of all an easy "helloWorld"

```
input("hello from Console.\nPress Enter to close it :)")
```

Just tried this one on a colleague's machine that has no python installed. And it worked well.

Comment: Yes. I've already created .exe with matplotlib, numpy, pythonnet and pywinauto as well. Some were with Python's version 3.6 and some with version 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results using the pyinstaller module to one file even when running code with multiple dependencies on machines without python installed. Reading the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/operating-mode.html) helped There is a comprehensive list of python to exe compilers in another stackoverflow question: [a good python to exe compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165398/a-good-python-to-exe-compiler)