# What is needed to run a python exe in Windows?

Tags: python

I am picking up a project that was created in python. Unfortunately, I do not know python and how it works with Windows. The code is done, but I need to get the .exe running on a server this running Windows Server 2008 r2. It was running before, but it no longer works.

What does the server need in order to run a compiled .exe that was written in python?

Comment: Nothing.  Python is not actually "compiled"; the script and all of its dependencies are packed into a "zip" file.  When you run the exe, it makes a miniature Python environment and runs the script.  What error do you see?  What version of Python did you use?  Server 2008R2 is very very old.  Python 3.9 no longer supports Windows 7 (which is the same as 2008R2).

Comment: Usually Python 'exe-builds' are not backward compatible to older Windows versions.

Comment: if you are looking for a way of creating that exe:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165398/a-good-python-to-exe-compiler